# Как передать class через socket в python

Tags: python, классы, сокет

К примеру я имею на сервере "class dog:"
Возможно ли передать этот класс клиенту через socket?

Comment: Нужно сериализовать данные, на клиенте десериализовать. Способов сериализации куча, один из очень часто используемый - json.

Answer (score 1):

Для ваших целей нужно использовать сериализацию и десереализацию обьектов.

Сериализация:

```
import _pickle as cPickle

dump = cPickle.dumps(object)
sock.send(dump)
```

Десериализация:

```
data = sock.recv(1024)
obj = cPickle.loads(data)
```

Подробнее [тут](https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/serialization-and-deserialization-of-python-objects-part-1--cms-26183).